# NSManagedObject's `isDeleted` yields different result if the object is a fault

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have encountered an unexpected situation where a managed object reports ambiguous results for `isDeleted` depending on wether it is a fault or not:

```
(lldb) po myManagedObject.isFault
true

(lldb) po myManagedObject.isDeleted
false

(lldb) po myManagedObject.type // access some property to fire the fault
""

(lldb) po myManagedObject.isFault
false

(lldb) po myManagedObject.isDeleted
true
```

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention – `myManagedObject.managedObjectContext` is *not* nil.

I would expect `isDeleted` to be consistent, the documentation doesn't say otherwise:

So how to deal with this? Do I need to fire faults before checking if an object is deleted or not? Or is there a deeper bug on my side to investigate.

Any insights on the matter would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSManagedObject+isdeleted

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, but NSManagedObjectContext is not nil, so your suggestion doesn't apply. Edited accordingly.